# Facebook Socialite login with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I have followed all the step in http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication to make the social login with facebook on Laravel 5.1.

Here the steps that I've followed:

1 - Use the command in my Laravel root project:

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

2 - register the Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider in your config/app.php configuration file:

```
'providers' => [
    // Other service providers...

    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
],
```

3 - Add the Socialite facade to the aliases array in your app configuration file:

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

4 - add the facebook services in config/services.php:

```
 'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://homestead.app/auth/facebook/callback',
    ],
```

5 - add to my AuthController.php the methods redirectToProvider() and handleProviderCallback():

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Redirect path after successful login
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectPath = '/greeting';

    /**
     * Redirect path after failed login
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $loginPath = '/auth/login';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Facebook authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */


    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Facebook.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        dd($user);
    }
}
```

I want to highlight that I have created AuthController.php in the folder app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ because after it asks to create the routes: 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider'
'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback'

6 -  I've added the routes:

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Now, when I click "Login with facebook" in my login page it goes to http://homestead.app/auth/facebook and get me the following error:

> FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 90: Class 'Socialite'
>   not found

I have tried to follow the codeanchor [guide](http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/complete-laravel-socialite-tutorial/) but it is for laravel 5.0 (I need to use that on laravel 5.1)

Comment: Try to use `composer dump-autoload` in your composer

Comment: I have just tried but nothing has changed

Comment: Are you using homestead database ? or local?

Comment: Have you tried to call the class including the whole namespace?
\Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect(); Just to test if the class is really unreachable - if this successes than something is wrong with your cache, the compiled class loader or something like this.
best thing is to run composer update again - this includes by default all the commands from artisan.

Comment: @Gummibeer I have just tried and it returns this error: `BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 744:
Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable.` @aldrin27 I am using homestead on vagrant on my local machine. What do you mean for homestead database? I'm sorry but I am starting with laravel a few weeks ago.

Comment: I googled a bit, cause I never had A similar error, and found nearly nothing. The only thing is that https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-bindingresolutionexception-error and this is nearly the same I suggested. Run composer again, remove the whole vendor and update, clear compiled (artisan command) and things like this - check the folder chmod for storage and bootstrap/cache.

Comment: @Gummibeer what do you mean for "remove the whole vendor and update"? And for "check folder chmod"?

Comment: Socialite is A package loaded via composer and all these are in the vendor folder - you can delete this folder and run composer update to secure that everything is up2date and there are no problems. The second is that laravel need write access to the storage and bootstrap/cache folder - for that is chmod to give the User that runs laravel/your Webserver write access.

Comment: @Gummibeer I have deleted the vendor folder and than run composer update. Nonthing have changed, Now I have checked bootstrap/cache folder and it told me: `drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Aug  8 19:04 bootstrap` for bootstrap folder and `drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Sep 16 21:30 cache` for cache folder. However I have just seen in phpstorm that when I write `use Socialite;` in AuthController.php file he writes above "undefined class Socialite".

Comment: Do you write `Socialite` or `\Socialite`? You are in a namespace and Socialite is in another namespace - it has an alias but that's for the root namespace.

Comment: Ok, I See that you use this class - if you use phpstorm I recommend xou the IDE helper to solve aliases and so on. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper and I have no more ideas ... :/

Comment: Finally I have solved with deleting everything and installing it again from the start

Comment: I mean reinstalling Homestead on vagrant from the start

Comment: @Giuseppe buddy answer your question down there and mark it as the solution just in case someone comes to this page looking for answers :)

Comment: Late suggestion but in case you come accross it in the future try deleting the `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file manually and then running the `composer dump-autoload` command. I had the same issue until someone pointed out to me there were issues with that file in my homestead environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved with deleting everything and installing Homestead again from the start

Comment: @mkmnstr Then just try to delete everything from the `vendor` folder and `composer install` it again.